# Using embedded objects with FIXTURES

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Using the `REST Adapter`, it is possible to have embedded objects by doing:

```
App.Adapter.map('App.User', {
    properties : {embedded: 'always'},
});
```

How do I declare embedded objects using a `FIXTURE`? I have tried specifying this in the model:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    properties : DS.belongsTo('App.UserProperties', { embedded : true })
});
```

But this is not working. Is it possible to have embedded objects using `FIXTURES`? My `FIXTURE` looks like:

```
App.User.FIXTURES = [
    { 
        id: 'id1',
        type: 'user', 
        properties : { 
            name: 'Max Smith',
            email: 'max.smith@email.com' }
    },
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FixtureAdapter` does not support embedded records, the only way to do this is to define `FIXTURES` for your `UserProperties` model as well:

```
App.User.FIXTURES = [
  { 
    id: 'id1',
    type: 'user', 
    properties : 1
];

App.UserProperties.FIXTURES = [
  { 
    id: '1',
    name: 'Max Smith',
    email: 'max.smith@email.com'
  }
];
```

Here also a quick statement from @tomdale (one of the creator of ember-data) on the `FixtureAdapter`

> I do not believe that fixture adapter supports embedded records
>   is there a good reason why it would need to?
>   it also doesn't support underscored_property_names
>   the idea of the fixture adapter is not to mimic the JSON payload from the server
>   it is provide stub data in the format Ember Data expects
>   so relationships are not embedded, property names are camelCased, etc.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Fair enough. But that, from my point of view, defeats an important goal of FIXTURES, namely to have the *exact* same json that the backend is providing, and be able to test the application as if the backend was there, with all the configured mappings, and other adapter configuration. With the stated approach, I must *manually* edit the json, which means I can (*will*) make errors. So now my "test data" must be tested. Not nice.